# Creality 1.2.3 does not recognize M140 and 104?

Tags: creality-ender-3, creality

For some reason, the Creality Slicer 1.2.3 ignores the `M140` and `M104` commands completely, even if I put them at the very beginning of the start G-code. I have tried different variations (e.g. `M140 S60`, `M140 S{material_bed_temperature}`, `M140 S{material_bed_temperature_layer_0}`, and none work with Creality Slicer 1.2.3.

Instead of starting the heating and not waiting to move to the next line, it waits to reach temperature as if it is an `M109` or `M190`. Does anyone have a similar experience or fix for the `M104` and `M140` commands in Creality Slicer 1.2.3? Using Creality Ender 3